# Is there a solution for this error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant?

Tags: c

I download the zip source code from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm

And I compile it on windows10 with Mingw-w64.

I use the following command to compile this source:

```
# mingw32-make -f win32/makefile.gcc zip.exe
gcc -c   -O3 -Wall -mms-bitfields  -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -DWIN32 -DZIP64_SUPPORT -DFORCE_WIN32_OVER_UNIX -DLARGE_FILE_SUPPORT -DUNICODE_SUPPORT -DUSE_EF_UT_TIME -DNTSD_EAS -DNO_STREAMING_STORE -ID:/Progra~1/GnuWin32/include -I. -ozip.o zip.c
```

And I get the following error:

```
In file included from zip.c:16:
zip.h:265:16: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 #define CR     13        /* '\r' on ASCII machines; must be 13 due to EBCDIC */
                ^~
mingw32-make: *** [win32/makefile.gcc:113: zip.o] Error 1
```

I try to comment this line which define CR, and it's works, but the compiler gives me another error about CR is undeclared.

```
zipup.c:1220:53: error: 'CR' undeclared (first use in this function)
             if ((*buf++ = *b++) == '\n') *(buf-1) = CR, *buf++ = LF, len++;
```

And I try to other ways to fix it by modify the code, but I don't know the reason of the error. And I don't know how to fix it.

I have replace the define like this: `#define CR 13`

And move the define line to other place in the file.

But the compiler also give me the same error:
(I move the define from line 265 to line 79)

```
In file included from zip.c:16:
zip.h:79:16: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 #define CR     13
                ^~
mingw32-make: *** [win32/makefile.gcc:113: zip.o] Error 1
```

I think the code for the define is correct, but I don't know why I get the error, and how to fix it.

Comment: I have no idea about this problem, and change the define into ```#define CR_EX     13 ```, and change the source code for this define, and it's OK.

Comment: What's the full error message? You're only showing the last part.